# Access old Windows files from Tails

Tags: linux, mount, 32-vs-64-bit, tails

I just installed Tails, but I can't seem to access my old Windows files. I'm prompted for the Windows admin password, but even when I enter the correct one it says it can't do it.

My gut feeling is that it's because Tails is a 32 bit system, and can't mount a 64 bit one.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Tails isn't asking for your Windows user profile password.  Tails wouldn't even know how to authenticate it.

Answer (score 3):

I might be completely on the wrong path here, but...

I'm unsure why it'd be asking for your windows password, that doesn't make sense unless you had some kind of encryption on the files. More than likely it's asking for the Tails Linux root password. There maybe a default on tails, or you might need to set it using sudo passwd root